# Operator Precedence in C - Returning a Value

Tags: c, operators, return, operator-precedence

I have this statement:

`return *local_stack_var2++ + 42;`

Would these be the proper steps when breaking it down:
1. Dereference local_stack_var2
2. Add 42 to the dereferenced local_stack_var2 (function will actually return this value)
3. Before the function is over, it will activate the post-increment, incrementing the value of the object pointed to by local_stack_var2

So in code format, it would look kind of something like this?

```
int temp = *local_stack_var2 //step 1;  
int returnValue = temp + 42; //step 2, compiler will return THIS value     
*local_stack_var2 = *local_stack_var2 + 1; //step 3 
 return returnValue;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Precedence precedence and precedence...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Close, but `++` (postincrement) has higher precedence than unary `*`, so it happens first. The order of operations would be:

1. Post increment `local_stack_var2` so that it is incremented by one but the expression evaluates to the original value, not the incremented value
2. Dereference that original value
3. add `42` to what was obtained by dereferencing the aforementioned original value
4. return that value

So in code, it would be *like* (not precisely, but close)

```
int* temp = local_stack_var2;
local_stack_var2 = local_stack_var2 + 1;
int retval = *temp;
reval = retval + 42;
return retval;
```

Comment: The postincrement does not necessarily happen *first*.  `++` having higher precedence than `*` means only that it is `local_stack_var2` that is incremented, not `*local_stack_var2` - the precedence controls *what* is incremented, not *when* it is incremented.  The actual increment can happen at any time until the function returns.

Comment: @caf yes, that is what I was thinking of when I put "like" in italics and added "(not precisely, but close)". Technically, no way you would write it would be correct because of that but I didn't think it was important enough to concern the OP with it.