# C++, Why ++ operator on iterator doesn't work, if put after expression, *(v.begin() + i / 10)++?

Tags: c++, iterator

This exercise is from Primer book (C++):

> Let’s assume that we have a collection of grades that range from 0 through 100. We’d like to count how many grades fall into various clusters of 10. Between zero and 100 there are 101 possible grades. These grades can be represented by 11 clusters: 10 clusters of 10 grades each plus one cluster for the perfect score of 100. The first cluster will count grades of 0 through 9, the second will count grades from 10 through 19, and so on. The final cluster counts how many scores of 100 were achieved.
>
> Clustering the grades this way, if our input is
>
> 42 65 95 100 39 67 95 76 88 76 83 92 76 93
>
> then the output should be
>
> 0 0 0 1 1 0 2 3 2 4 1

```
int main() 
{
    vector<int> v(11, 0);
    int i;
    while (cin >> i)
    {
        ++*(v.begin() + i / 10); 
    }
    for (auto& r : v)
    {
        cout << r << '\t';
    }
    cout << endl;
        
    return 0;
}
```

If the line

`++*(v.begin() + i / 10);`

is changed to

`*(v.begin() + i / 10)++;`

The program reads nothing to the vector.  Why?

Comment: Lookup [_operator precedence_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) to see which operator would be evaluated first.

Comment: aside: why not `++v[i / 10]` / `v[i / 10]++`?

Comment: Simplify and leave out the iterator arithmetic.  Just think about `++*it` vs `(*it)++` vs `*(it++)`

Comment: You're only confusing yourself by writing code like this. The compiler mechanically follows the rules to interpret it. It's free to add extra variables for readability only, such as `int scaled_score = i/10`. The compiler won't need to allocate extra memory for that.

Comment: both versions are unreadable so best you refactor this line

Comment: [This answer discusses operator precedence of the `*x++` pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8379839/)

Comment: @Caleth, i forgot to mention, task was not to use subscript operator

Comment: So why not `v.at(i / 10)`?

Comment: @Caleth because i haven't learnt what "at" is ,)

Comment: [`std::vector::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) is like [`std::vector::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at), except that out-of-range access throws std::out_of_range rather than being undefined behaviour

Comment: One would hope that homework that asked to not use `[]` was to teach you of the existence of `at`, rather than the hideous `*(v.begin() + i / 10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the expression `++*(v.begin() + i / 10);`, the `begin()` iterator is first incremented by `i / 10`, then the resulting iterator is dereferenced, and then the `int` being referred to is incremented.

But in the expression `*(v.begin() + i / 10)++;`, the `begin()` iterator is first incremented by `i / 10`, same as above. But due to [Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the `++` operator has a higher precedence than the `*` operator, so the resulting iterator is incremented and then dereferenced.  The `int` being referred to is left untouched.

Comment: in case with '*(v.begin() + i / 10)++;' if 'i' is 55, iterator is incremented  to 5,  then '++' operator makes it 6, and then '*' operator dereferences to 6th element without any change......i got it while writing it, thanks)

Answer (score 0):

I worked through the same problem (with textbook examples) and was able to solve it using iterators. See code below.

```
// Exercise_3.25.cpp : Rewrite the grade clustering program from 3.3.3 (p. 104) using iterators instead of subscripts.

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

#include <vector>
using std::vector;

int main()
{
    // count the number of grades by clusters of ten: 0--9, 10--19, ... 90--99, 100
    vector<unsigned> scores(11, 0);

    // hold the grades we read from the standard input
    vector<unsigned> grades;

    // 42 65 95 100 39 67 95 76 88 76 83 92 76 93
    unsigned grade;

    while (cin >> grade)    // read the grades
    {
        if (grade <= 100)   // handle only valid grades
        {
            grades.push_back(grade);
        }
    }

    // for each grade in the input
    for (auto iter = grades.begin(); iter != grades.end(); iter++)
    {
        unsigned i = *iter;
        // increment the counter for the current cluster
        (*(scores.begin() + i / 10))++;
    }

    for (auto iter = scores.cbegin(); iter != scores.cend(); iter++)
    {
        cout << *iter << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```